# RecyclerAdapter com diferentes layouts

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Gostaria de saber como usar um layout diferente com o esquema abaixo apresentado,
se eu estiver na Atividade A mostrar Layout 1, se eu estiver na Atividade B mostrar Layout 2, vi que se faz com viewType , mais não consegui entender como o viewType funciona, se puderem explicar como funciona eu agradeço.
no meu caso só tem que mudar mesmo o layout os resto é tudo igual.

```
public class RecyclerViewTeste extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewTeste .MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Blog> mQuestionList;
    Context mContext;


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;
        TextView title,desc,nome,data,uid,cont,mRetes;
        ImageView mExpand;
        CircleImageView mCirclePerfil;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mContext = mView.getContext();

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_username);
            data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datarow);
            uid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.uid);
        }
        public void setFtperfil(Context ctx, String ftperfil) {
            CircleImageView post_perfil = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imagemPerfil);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(ftperfil).into(post_perfil);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewClashOfClans(List<Blog> mQuestionList) {
        this.mQuestionList = mQuestionList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.blog_row_cliente, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Blog blog = mQuestionList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(blog.getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(blog.getDesc());
        holder.nome.setText(blog.getNome());
        holder.data.setText(blog.getData());
        holder.uid.setText(blog.getId_post());
        holder.setFtperfil(getApplicationContext(), blog.getFoto());

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent singleBlogIntent = new Intent(mContext, BlogSingleActivityClash.class);

                singleBlogIntent.putExtra("blog_id", blog.getId_post());
                mContext.startActivity(singleBlogIntent);

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mQuestionList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: O layout da lista somente que mudaria, ou mudaria também os objetos que seriam mostrados, no caso a mQuestionList?

Comment: no caso só o layout, acontece que eu uso o mesmo código 5 vezes no meu app só que ele é apresentado de diferentes maneira dependendo de onde o usuário esteja, eu só quero diminuir linhas de codiogo mesmo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso mais do que o getItemViewType para resolver o problema. 
Primeiro você tem que definir o que você quer.

No seu caso, achei estranha a abordagem de mudar o layout dos itens do RecyclerView de acordo com a Activity que chama. Tipo, você está reaproveitando o mesmo RecyclerView para cada Activity? Por que não implementar uma RecyclerView por Activity com seus próprios adapters?

Mas enfim, explicando sua dúvida, quem vai definir os tipos de layout por item da RecyclerView são os dados de origem que você vai carregar no Adapter.

No seu caso parece ser o `List<Blog>`. Então é preciso ter alguma variável na sua classe Blog que diferencie uma instância da outra de acordo com o valor dessa variável, se não tiver, crie uma e, sempre que criar um objeto dessa classe, inicialize a variável com tipo desejado, pois tudo que o getItemViewType vai fazer é ler essa variável do objeto em cada posição do Array.

Por exemplo:
Se a sua classe Blog tiver uma variável "tipo" (que pode ser recuperada com um método getTipo), no getItemViewType() você pode criar um switch() que vai fazer o método retornar o tipo necessário que você irá trabalhar no Adapter para cada item do array.

```
 private final int TIPO1 = 0;
 private final int TIPO2 = 1;
 private final int TIPO3 = 2;

 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int tipo = mQuestionList.get(position).getTipo();
    switch(tipo){
       case TIPO1: return TIPO1;
       case TIPO2: return TIPO2;
       case TIPO1: return TIPO3;
    }
}
```

Com isso, nos demais métodos do adapter (onCreateViewHolder e onBindViewHolder), você também vai precisar criar switch's parecidos para fazer o carregamento do layout de acordo com o tipo.

E claro, você tem que ter um ViewHolder diferente para cada layout necessário e que você tem que usar de acordo com os switchs criados nos métodos acima.

Nesse link, tem um bom tutorial:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: acho que estou intendendo, tipo eu uso o firebase.. se no model eu mandar TIPO 1, na hora de preencher a lista ele ira diferencia pelo TIPO "0,1,2,3" correto?

Comment: Isso aí, deve funcionar. A menos que você já tenha alguma variável na sua classe que já dê para diferenciar um objeto do outro pelo valor da mesma, então você não precisaria criar uma nova.

Comment: era exatamente isso que eu não entendia,você clareou minha mente, uns messes atras fiz uma pergunta de como usar layout para destinatório e remetente num chat, só que não havia entendido isto, agora sei que é só criar um código para diferenciar o id do cliente, mais nesta questão irei continuar com os adapter separado mesmo, Valeu!